# Make bootable USB Drive from Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, windows, flash, drive

I need Windows for a few things, and while I love Ubuntu. I think I'll have to install Windows agian for a short period of time.

I got the .iso file on my desktop, and need to make it bootable from a flash drive. It's pretty easy from Windows, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it from Ubuntu.

I've searched on Google and here as well, but all I can find is how to make it from OS X, Windows.. Or how to make a bootable flash drive with Ubuntu from Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess any bootable usb creator would do it as long as they can put an iso file on a usb flash drive. An important point, your usb flash drive should be formatted in NTFS. I know that some of the bootable usb creators do not work with NTFS, however do not have recent knowledge on ones that work with it.

Comment: doesn't microsoft already sells bootable usb keys?

Comment: "I think I'll have to install Windows agian for a short period of time." There is another option --- use VirtualBox for a virtual windows machine. If you are not planning to play modern games it would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the program: unetbootin

Install it if you don't already have it.

Click Diskimage>ISO  Then navigate to ISO.

This makes a static version, like a LiveCD so it is unchangeable.

To make a version you can add to you need to make a "persistent" USB stick. Look here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

Comment: somethimes we need to read again, he's talking about windows iso not ubuntu or any other linux iso

Comment: Yes I am. You should be able to make a Windows bootable wih unetbootin as well, problem is that when I did that. When I booted from USB, the only option I had was "default" - and whenever I clicked that, the screen would just refresh.

Comment: @ Angel Salinas Huerta Yes you are right. Only the bit about persistence is wrong! There is a link to making a Windows 7 bootable USB stick on Ubuntu using Unetbootin here: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu desktop application name startup disk can make the bootable flash disk from .iso file

find it in unity app named as start-up disk

here is the video of how to do it [Bootable flash disk using Startup disk app in ubuntu](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaP6nin7sFw)

Comment: +1 In KDE, you can find it in Settings -> Startup Disk Creator

Comment: it does not recognize Windows installation iso